# PHP Carbon specialized date format

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I want to make a function that will output a result like this:

```
//Assuming that today is 2022-01-20
parse_date("2022-01-20") //Today
parse_date("2022-01-19") //Yesterday
parse_date("2022-01-18") //Tuesday
parse_date("2022-01-17") //Monday
parse_date("2022-01-16") //Sunday
parse_date("2022-01-15") //2022-01-15
```

The idea is to display `Today` if the date is today, `Yesterday` if the date is yesterday, the weekday name if the date is within the current week and `Y-m-d` for anything else.
The current code I have that works is as follows:

```php
public function parse_date($date) {
    $carbonDate = Carbon::parse($date);
    if($carbonDate->isToday()) return "Today";
    if($carbonDate->isYesterday()) return "Yesterday";
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $start = $now->startOfWeek(CarbonInterface::SUNDAY)->copy();
    if($carbonDate >= $start && $carbonDate <= $now->endOfWeek(CarbonInterface::SATURDAY)->copy()) {
        return $carbonDate->format('l');
    }
    
    return $carbonDate->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

What I want to know is if there's a better way to do this using other Carbon functions.

Comment: There is `->isCurrentWeek()`, but note that it apparently uses Monday as the start of the week, depending on your system

Comment: Yea that's why I didn't use is, if that start day can be changed then I'll implement it.

Comment: I thought changing the locale would work, but apparently not. `Carbon\Carbon::parse("2022-01-16")->locale('en_US')->isCurrentWeek(); // false`

Comment: Check the `calendar()` method in the carbon documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is to check the week, and compare it to the current week. Double-check the values first to make sure this works, or if you need to change the locale, with `Carbon::parse($date)->locale('en_US');`

```
public function parse_date($date) {
    $carbonDate = Carbon::parse($date);
    if($carbonDate->isToday()) return "Today";
    if($carbonDate->isYesterday()) return "Yesterday";
    if($carbonDate->week == Carbon::now()->week) {
        return $carbonDate->format('l');
    }
    
    return $carbonDate->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: Seems to work the same without needing to change the local. Cleaner than the current code, so accepting this unless something cleaner comes up.

Comment: I just realized this only checks for the week, but not the year, so may not work in all situations.

Comment: Just did a test to check and yea, it doesn't take year into account, so it won't work for my situation.

Comment: You can add `&& $carbonDate->year == Carbon::now()->year` to the if statement, but it won't account for weeks crossing years.